# when clicked on button "reschedule scheduled service" spinner keeps on loading

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, aura-framework

trying to reschedule the calim but when clicked on button spinner keeps on rotating and unable to reschedule

see the screenshots for the error

Creatfurniturecontroller.js

```
createFurnitureServiceInfo : function(component) {
    var scheduleServiceWrapper = component.get('v.scheduleService');
    var scheduleServiceWrappperComments = scheduleServiceWrapper.Comments.replace(/\\/g, '');
    var escapedComments = this.encodeSpecialCharacters(scheduleServiceWrappperComments);
    scheduleServiceWrapper.Comments = escapedComments;
    scheduleServiceWrapper.ButtonLabel = component.get('v.buttonLabel');
    component.set('v.isLoading',true);
    var isIndependentServicer = component.get('v.isIndependentServicerChecked');
    var independentServicer = component.get('v.independentServicer');
    var action = component.get('c.createFurnitureServices');
    var parameters = {
        "scheduleServiceJSON": JSON.stringify(scheduleServiceWrapper),
        "independentServicerJSON": JSON.stringify(independentServicer),
        "isIndependentServicer": isIndependentServicer
    };
    //console.log('params: ' + JSON.stringify(parameters));
    action.setParams(parameters);
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        component.set('v.isLoading',false);
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            this.displayToast('Success', 'The service has been successfully scheduled.','success');
            var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
            navEvt.setParams({
                "recordId": response.getReturnValue(),
                "slideDevName": "detail"
            });
            this.closeModal(component);

            this.refreshFurnitureServiceRecord();
            navEvt.fire();
        } else {
            console.error(response.getError());
            this.displayToast('Error', 'Something went wrong, the service was NOT scheduled. Please verify zip code and additional address fields.','error');
        }            
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
refreshFurnitureServiceRecord : function() {
    window.setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            var refreshFurnitureServiceEvent = $A.get("e.c:refreshFurnitureServiceEvent");
            refreshFurnitureServiceEvent.fire();
        }), 2000
    );
},
getDayOfWeek : function(serviceDate) {
    var momentDate = moment(serviceDate);
    var weekDay = momentDate.format('dddd');
    return weekDay;
},
formatServiceDate : function(serviceDate) {
    return serviceDate.substring(5, 7) + '/' + serviceDate.substring(8, 10) + '/' + serviceDate.substring(0, 4);
},
displayToast : function(title, message, type, mode){
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        title : title,
        message: message,
        duration:' 5000',
        key: 'info_alt',
        type: type,
        mode: mode ? mode : 'pester'
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
},
getRelatedCase : function(component, event, helper) {
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
        //console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)));
        var parentTabId = response.parentTabId;
        workspaceAPI.getTabInfo({
            tabId: parentTabId
        }).then(function(parentTabResponse) {
            var parentTabObjectAPIName = parentTabResponse.pageReference.attributes.objectApiName;
            //console.log(parentTabObjectAPIName);
            // If the parent tab is a Case record
            if(parentTabObjectAPIName === "Case"){
                var caseRecord = {
                    "recordId" : parentTabResponse.recordId,
                    "label" : parentTabResponse.title
                }
                component.set('v.caseRecord',caseRecord);
            } else {
                // If the parent tab is not a Case record
                var relatedSubTabs = parentTabResponse.subtabs;
                for (let i = 0; i < relatedSubTabs.length; i++) {
                    var subtab = relatedSubTabs[i];
                    var subTabObjectAPIName = subtab.pageReference.attributes.objectApiName;
                    if(subTabObjectAPIName === "Case"){
                        var caseRecord = {
                            "recordId" : subtab.recordId,
                            "label" : subtab.title
                        }
                        component.set('v.caseRecord',caseRecord);
                    }
                }
            }
            helper.fetchCaseData(component, event, helper);
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
},

isValidToSave : function(component, event, helper) {
    var validityErrors = [];
    var notPopulatedRequiredFields = [];
    var isIndependentServicer = component.get('v.isIndependentServicerChecked');
    try {  
        // validation for both: regular and independent servicer scheduling 
        let serviceDateField = isIndependentServicer ? component.find('serviceDate2') : component.find('serviceDate');
        serviceDateField.reportValidity();
        if (!serviceDateField.get('v.value')) validityErrors.push('Service Date must be selected.');
        let addressField = isIndependentServicer ? component.find('addressField2a') : component.find('addressField');
        addressField.reportValidity();
        if (!addressField.get('v.value')) notPopulatedRequiredFields.push('address');
        let zipCodeField = isIndependentServicer ? component.find('zipCodeField2') : component.find('zipCodeField');
        zipCodeField.reportValidity();
        if (!zipCodeField.get('v.value')) notPopulatedRequiredFields.push('zip code');
        let stateField = isIndependentServicer ? component.find('stateField2') : component.find('stateField');
        stateField.reportValidity();
        if (!stateField.get('v.value')) notPopulatedRequiredFields.push('state');
        let cityField = isIndependentServicer ? component.find('cityField2') : component.find('cityField');
        cityField.reportValidity();
        if (!cityField.get('v.value')) notPopulatedRequiredFields.push('city');
        // validation for independent servicer scheduling
        if (isIndependentServicer) {            
            var caseRecord = component.get('v.caseRecord');
            if (!caseRecord || !caseRecord.Id) validityErrors.push('Selecting case related to service is required.');
            if (!caseRecord.Independent_Servicer__r) {
                validityErrors.push('Independent Servicer needs to be assigned to the selected Case.');
            } else if (!caseRecord.Independent_Servicer__r.Servicer_Id__c)  {
                validityErrors.push('Independent Servicer assigned to the selected Case needs to have Servicer Id value.');
            }
            let callBackContactField = component.find('callBackContact');
            callBackContactField.reportValidity();
            if (!callBackContactField.get('v.value')) notPopulatedRequiredFields.push('contact');
            let callBackNumberField = component.find('callBackNumber');
            callBackNumberField.reportValidity();
            if (!callBackNumberField.get('v.value')) {
                notPopulatedRequiredFields.push('phone');
            } else if (callBackNumberField.get('v.value').length != 10) {
                validityErrors.push('Phone field must be 10 digits long.');
            }
        } else {
            // validation for regular scheduling
            var routeCode = component.get('v.selectedRouteCode');
            if($A.util.isUndefinedOrNull(routeCode) || $A.util.isEmpty(routeCode) || routeCode.trim() == ''){
                validityErrors.push('A Route code is required.');
            }
            var selectedAvailableAppointmentUnits = Number(component.get('v.selectedAppointmentUnits'));
            var availableUnits = Number(component.get('v.scheduleService.AppointmentUnits'));
            if(availableUnits > selectedAvailableAppointmentUnits){
                validityErrors.push('There is not enough appointment units available for the selected service date.');
            }
        }
        if (isIndependentServicer) {            
            if (notPopulatedRequiredFields.length > 0) validityErrors.push('You need to populate those fields on the selected case: ' + notPopulatedRequiredFields.join(', ') + '.');
        } else {
            if (notPopulatedRequiredFields.length > 0) validityErrors.push('You need to populate those fields: ' + notPopulatedRequiredFields.join(', ') + '.');
        }
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    return validityErrors;
},
isIndependentServicerCheckedChanged : function(component, event, helper) {
    let checkboxValue = component.get('v.isIndependentServicerChecked');
    try{
        // If the checkbox was checked
        if(checkboxValue){
            // Set service date as current date
            component.set('v.selectedServiceDate', new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10));
            let caseRecord = component.get('v.caseRecord');
            let scheduleService = component.get('v.scheduleService');
            // If this property is already filled, it means the service was already scheduled once, so we should consider data from POPS
            if(scheduleService.Servicer){
                let independentServicer = {
                    CustomerName  : scheduleService.CustomerName,
                    Address : scheduleService.Address,
                    ZipCode :  scheduleService.ZipCode,
                    State :  scheduleService.State,
                    City :  scheduleService.City,
                    ContactPhone :  scheduleService.ContactPhone,
                    ContactPhoneExtension :  scheduleService.ContactPhoneExtension,
                    Servicer : caseRecord.Independent_Servicer__r.Servicer_Id__c,
                    CaseId : caseRecord.Id
                };
                component.set('v.independentServicer',independentServicer);
            } else {
                // This means it's the first time creating the independent servicer furniture service, so we should consider data from the associated Case
                let independentServicer = {
                    CustomerName  : caseRecord.Call_Back_Contact__c,
                    Address : caseRecord.Shipping_Address_1__c,
                    ZipCode : caseRecord.Shipping_Postal_Code__c,
                    State :  caseRecord.Shipping_State__c,
                    City :  caseRecord.Shipping_City__c,
                    ContactPhone :  caseRecord.Requested_Call_Back_Number__c,
                    ContactPhoneExtension :  caseRecord.Requested_Call_Back_Number_Ext__c,
                    Servicer : caseRecord.Independent_Servicer__r.Servicer_Id__c,
                    CaseId : caseRecord.Id
                };
                component.set('v.independentServicer',independentServicer);
            }
        } else {
            component.set('v.selectedServiceDate', null);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    
}
```

})

Apex class

public without sharing class CreateFurnitureServicesCtrl {

```
@AuraEnabled
public static ScheduleServiceWrapper getScheduleServiceWrapper(String claimRecordId){
    String[] claimFieldsList = new List<String>{
        'Id', 'OrderNumber__c','AccountNumber__c', 'ClaimId__c'
    };
    Map<String,String> claimsFieldValueMap = new Map<String,String>();
    claimsFieldValueMap.put('Id',claimRecordId);
    Claims__x objClaims = nfm_ExternalClaimRequest.getClaims(claimFieldsList, claimsFieldValueMap, 'Id', 'ASC')[0];
    
    String[] orderDetailsFieldsList = new List<String>{
        'Id','CustomerZip__c','CustomerPhone__c','OrderState__c','OrderCity__c','CustomerState__c','CustomerCity__c','DistributionMethod__c', 
            'AccountNumber__c','OrderNumber__c','OrderZip__c', 'OrderPrimaryCallAhPhExt__c', 'CustomerName__c',
            'CustomerAddress1__c','CustomerAddress2__c','OrderAddress1__c','OrderAddress2__c'
    };  
    Map<String,String> orderDetailsFieldValueMap = new Map<String,String>();
    orderDetailsFieldValueMap.put('OrderNumber__c',objClaims.OrderNumber__c);
    OrderDetails__x objOrderDetails = nfm_ExternalOrderDetailsRequest.getOrders(orderDetailsFieldsList, orderDetailsFieldValueMap, 'Id', 'ASC', false)[0];
    
    ScheduleServiceWrapper objScheduleServiceWrapper = new ScheduleServiceWrapper();
    objScheduleServiceWrapper.NumberOfDays = 15;
    objScheduleServiceWrapper.AppointmentUnits = 1;
    objScheduleServiceWrapper.StartDate = String.valueOf(System.today());
    
    objScheduleServiceWrapper.ClaimId = objClaims.ClaimId__c;
    
    objScheduleServiceWrapper.ServiceDate = 'TBD';
    objScheduleServiceWrapper.RouteCode = 'TBD';
    objScheduleServiceWrapper.ServiceCode = 'TBD';
    objScheduleServiceWrapper.Comments = ' ';
    
    FurnitureServices__x objFurnitureServices = getPreviousFurnitureService(objClaims.ClaimId__c);
    
    Set<String> customerDistributionSet = new Set<String>{'P','T'};
    Set<String> orderDistributionSet = new Set<String>{'D','W','I','O'};
    
    // Here we're verifying if a basic field is blank, so that means that the furnite service hasn't been scheduled yet
    if(objFurnitureServices.InspectAddress1__c == null){
        
        // In this case, the details are filled according to the Order's Delivery Method
    
        objScheduleServiceWrapper.CustomerName = objOrderDetails.CustomerName__c;
        objScheduleServiceWrapper.ContactName = objOrderDetails.CustomerName__c;
        objScheduleServiceWrapper.ContactPhone = objOrderDetails.CustomerPhone__c;
        if(customerDistributionSet.contains(objOrderDetails.DistributionMethod__c)){ // Customer
            objScheduleServiceWrapper.City = objOrderDetails.CustomerCity__c;
            objScheduleServiceWrapper.State = objOrderDetails.CustomerState__c;
            objScheduleServiceWrapper.ZipCode = objOrderDetails.CustomerZip__c.substring(0,5);
            objScheduleServiceWrapper.Address = objOrderDetails.CustomerAddress1__c + ' ' + nfm_Utils.ifNull(objOrderDetails.CustomerAddress2__c,'');
        } else if(orderDistributionSet.contains(objOrderDetails.DistributionMethod__c)) { //Order
            objScheduleServiceWrapper.City = objOrderDetails.OrderCity__c;
            objScheduleServiceWrapper.State = objOrderDetails.OrderState__c;
            objScheduleServiceWrapper.ZipCode = objOrderDetails.OrderZip__c.substring(0,5);
            objScheduleServiceWrapper.ContactPhoneExtension = objOrderDetails.OrderPrimaryCallAhPhExt__c;
            objScheduleServiceWrapper.Address = objOrderDetails.OrderAddress1__c + ' ' + nfm_Utils.ifNull(objOrderDetails.OrderAddress2__c,'');
        }
        
    } else {
        // In this case, the details are filled according to the previous Furniture Service
        objScheduleServiceWrapper.CustomerName = objFurnitureServices.InspectName__c;
        objScheduleServiceWrapper.ContactName = objFurnitureServices.ContactDescription__c;
        objScheduleServiceWrapper.ContactPhone = objFurnitureServices.ContactPhone__c;
        objScheduleServiceWrapper.ContactPhoneExtension = objFurnitureServices.ContactPhoneExtension__c;
        objScheduleServiceWrapper.Address = objFurnitureServices.InspectAddress1__c;
        objScheduleServiceWrapper.City = objFurnitureServices.InspectCity__c;
        objScheduleServiceWrapper.State = objFurnitureServices.InspectState__c;
        objScheduleServiceWrapper.ZipCode = objFurnitureServices.InspectZip__c.substring(0,5);
    }
    
    objScheduleServiceWrapper.Servicer = nfm_Utils.ifNull(objFurnitureServices.Servicer__c,'');
    
    return objScheduleServiceWrapper;
}


public class ScheduleServiceWrapper{
    
    @AuraEnabled public String ClaimId{get;set;}   
    
    @AuraEnabled public String ZipCode{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String StartDate{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String ServiceDate{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String ServiceCode{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String RouteCode{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Integer NumberOfDays{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Integer AppointmentUnits{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled public String CustomerName{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String Address{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled public String Servicer{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled public String State{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String City{get;set;}
    
    @AuraEnabled public String ContactName{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String ContactPhone{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String ContactPhoneExtension{get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled public String Comments{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String ButtonLabel{get;set;}
    
} 

public class IndependentServicerWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled public String CustomerName{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String Address{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String State{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String City{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String ZipCode{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String ContactPhone{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String ContactPhoneExtension{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String Servicer{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String CaseId{get;set;}
}

@AuraEnabled
public static String createFurnitureServices(String scheduleServiceJSON, String independentServicerJSON, Boolean isIndependentServicer){
    ScheduleServiceWrapper objScheduleServiceWrapper = (ScheduleServiceWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(scheduleServiceJSON, ScheduleServiceWrapper.class);
    IndependentServicerWrapper objIndependentServicerWrapper = !isIndependentServicer ? null : (IndependentServicerWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(independentServicerJSON, IndependentServicerWrapper.class);
    JSONGenerator jsonGenerator = JSON.createGenerator(false);
    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
    jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('ClaimId__c', objScheduleServiceWrapper.ClaimId);    
    jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('Comments__c','[' + System.today().format() + '][' + nfm_Utils.userAlias + '] ' + objScheduleServiceWrapper.Comments);
    
    String inspectDateYear = objScheduleServiceWrapper.ServiceDate.substring(0,4);
    String inspectDateMonth = objScheduleServiceWrapper.ServiceDate.substring(5,7);
    String inspectDateDay = objScheduleServiceWrapper.ServiceDate.substring(8,10);
    jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectDate__c', inspectDateMonth + '/' + inspectDateDay + '/'+ inspectDateYear);

    if (!isIndependentServicer) {
        //specific fields
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectName__c', objScheduleServiceWrapper.CustomerName);   
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('ServiceCode__c', objScheduleServiceWrapper.ServiceCode);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('RouteCode__c', objScheduleServiceWrapper.RouteCode);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('AppointmentUnits__c', String.valueOf(objScheduleServiceWrapper.AppointmentUnits));
        //common fields
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectAddress1__c', objScheduleServiceWrapper.Address);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectAddress2__c', '');
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectCity__c', objScheduleServiceWrapper.City);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectState__c', objScheduleServiceWrapper.State);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectZip__c', objScheduleServiceWrapper.ZipCode);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('ContactPhone__c', objScheduleServiceWrapper.ContactPhone);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('ContactPhoneExtension__c', nfm_Utils.IfNull(objScheduleServiceWrapper.ContactPhoneExtension,''));    
    }

    if (isIndependentServicer) {
        //specific fields
        String servicerCode = Test.isRunningTest() ? '12345' : objIndependentServicerWrapper.Servicer;
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('Servicer__c', servicerCode); //servicer 5-digit code
        //common fields
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectAddress1__c', objIndependentServicerWrapper.Address);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectAddress2__c', '');
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField();
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectCity__c', objIndependentServicerWrapper.City);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectState__c', objIndependentServicerWrapper.State);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectZip__c', objIndependentServicerWrapper.ZipCode);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('InspectName__c', objIndependentServicerWrapper.CustomerName);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('ContactPhone__c', objIndependentServicerWrapper.ContactPhone);
        jsonGenerator.writeObjectField('ContactPhoneExtension__c', nfm_Utils.IfNull(objIndependentServicerWrapper.ContactPhoneExtension,'')); 
    }

    String jsonBody = '\'' + jsonGenerator.getAsString() + '\'';
    String jsonResult = nfm_FurnitureServicesCallout.upsertFurnitureServicesCallout(jsonBody);
    String result = '';
    if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
        Map<String, Object> jsonResultMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonResult);
        String[] furnitureServicesFieldsList = new List<String>{ 'ExternalId','Id','AppointmentUnits__c','InspectAddress1__c','InspectName__c','InspectDate__c' };
        Map<String,String> furnitureServicesFieldValueMap = new Map<String,String>();
        furnitureServicesFieldValueMap.put('ClaimId__c', String.valueOf(jsonResultMap.get('ClaimId')));
        FurnitureServices__x objFurnitureServices = nfm_ExternalFurnitureServicesRequest.getFurnitureServices(furnitureServicesFieldsList, furnitureServicesFieldValueMap, 'Id', 'ASC')[0];
        
        UserActivityController.createRecord(objScheduleServiceWrapper.ButtonLabel, 'Claim', objScheduleServiceWrapper.ClaimId);
        
        if(isIndependentServicer){
            updateServiceAssignedDate(objIndependentServicerWrapper.CaseId, Date.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(inspectDateYear), Integer.valueOf(inspectDateMonth), Integer.valueOf(inspectDateDay)));
        }
        
        return objFurnitureServices.Id;
    } else {
        result = 'ok';
    }
    return result;
}

public static FurnitureServices__x getPreviousFurnitureService(String claimId){
    Map<String,String> furnitureServicesFieldValueMap = new Map<String,String>();
    furnitureServicesFieldValueMap.put('ClaimId__c', claimId);
    return nfm_ExternalFurnitureServicesRequest.getFurnitureServices(SObjectUtils.getAllFieldsAPINames('FurnitureServices__x'), furnitureServicesFieldValueMap, 'Id', 'ASC')[0];
}


@AuraEnabled
public static List<FurnitureServiceRoutes__x> getFurnitureServiceRoutes(String startDate,String numberOfDays,String zipCode){
    String[] furnitureServiceRoutesFieldsList = new List<String>{
        'Id', 'NumberOfDays__c', 'RouteCode__c', 'RouteDescription__c', 'ServiceCode__c', 'StartDate__c', 'ZipCode__c'
    };
    Map<String,String> furnitureServiceRoutesFieldValueMap = new Map<String,String>();
    furnitureServiceRoutesFieldValueMap.put('NumberOfDays__c',numberOfDays);
    furnitureServiceRoutesFieldValueMap.put('StartDate__c',startDate);
    furnitureServiceRoutesFieldValueMap.put('ZipCode__c',zipCode);
    return nfm_ExternalFurnitureServiceRoutesReq.getFurnitureServiceRoutes(furnitureServiceRoutesFieldsList, furnitureServiceRoutesFieldValueMap, 'RouteCode__c', 'ASC');
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<FurnitureServiceAppointments__x> getFurnitureServiceAppointments(String startDate,String numberOfDays,String zipCode, String routeCode){
    String[] furnitureServiceAppointmentsFieldsList = new List<String>{
        'Id', 'AppointmentUnits__c', 'ServiceDate__c', 'StartDate__c', 'ZipCode__c','RouteCode__c'
    };
    Map<String,String> furnitureServiceAppointmentsFieldValueMap = new Map<String,String>();
    furnitureServiceAppointmentsFieldValueMap.put('NumberOfDays__c',numberOfDays);
    furnitureServiceAppointmentsFieldValueMap.put('StartDate__c',startDate);
    furnitureServiceAppointmentsFieldValueMap.put('ZipCode__c',zipCode);
    furnitureServiceAppointmentsFieldValueMap.put('RouteCode__c',routeCode);
    return nfm_ExternalFurnitureServiceAppRequest.getFurnitureServiceAppointments(furnitureServiceAppointmentsFieldsList, furnitureServiceAppointmentsFieldValueMap, 'RouteCode__c', 'ASC');
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean hasAccessToIndependentServicerPermset(){
    Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    String permsetApiName = 'Custom_Contact_Center_Support_Team';
    return nfm_Utils.isPermsetAssignedToUser(userId, permsetApiName);
}

**@AuraEnabled
public static Case retrieveCaseObject(Id caseId){
    return [
        SELECT 
            Id, Shipping_Address_1__c, Shipping_Address_2__c, Shipping_City__c, Shipping_State__c, 
            Shipping_Postal_Code__c, Call_Back_Contact__c, Requested_Call_Back_Number__c,
            Requested_Call_Back_Number_Ext__c ,Independent_Servicer__r.Id, Independent_Servicer__r.Servicer_Id__c, Independent_Servicer__r.Name
        FROM Case
        WHERE Id = :caseId
        LIMIT 1
    ];
}**

public static void updateServiceAssignedDate(Id caseId, date newDate){
    Case objCase =  [SELECT Id, Service_Assigned_Date__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId LIMIT 1];
    objCase.Service_Assigned_Date__c = newDate;
    update objCase;
}
```

}

**method to fetch case record**

```
 fetchCaseData : function(component, event, helper) {
    var caseRecord = component.get('v.caseRecord');
    var newCaseId = caseRecord.recordId; 
    var retrieveCaseAction = component.get('c.retrieveCaseObject');
    var actionParams = {'caseId':newCaseId};
    retrieveCaseAction.setParams(actionParams);
    retrieveCaseAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            //console.log('RESULT: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
            var currentCaseRecord = component.get('v.caseRecord');
            result.label = currentCaseRecord.label;
            result.recordId = currentCaseRecord.recordId;
            component.set('v.caseRecord', result);
            component.set('v.isLoading', false);
        } else {
            console.log(response.getError());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(retrieveCaseAction);
},
```

when clicked on reschedule spinner should not spin continuously

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4ny2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUx4C.png)

should be able to reschedule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs more info (but too long for comment).

Which JS function is called when that button (quick action?) is clicked? It doesn't look like you followed the customary `{!c.doInit}` naming convention.

You pasted a lot of code, `servicer_id__c` appears in 3 places. Next time try to cut the useless pieces until you're left with [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Check Apex Developer Console for errors / problems, maybe one of the functions genuinely returns null / throws error:

- lack of permissions to run this apex class
- really bad data (Case without some lookup populated?)
- maybe you carefully created a wrapper class to hold stuff returned from apex - but you forgot to mark every field as public and @AuraEnabled

I suspect the bad code is around places like `caseRecord.Independent_Servicer__r.Servicer_Id__c` in isIndependentServicerCheckedChanged. You don't check if the middle part is null. A ternary operator or [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) could make it easier to spot.

Enable Setup -> Debug mode (if not done already) and next time just click that error logged in JavaScript console. You'll be taken to the line in source code where it happened. It won't look exactly like your source code (SF transpiles a bit and merges multiple files into 1) but it should be close enough for you to recognise and fix the mistake. Or at least put some breakpoints / watches.

Comment: i have update the apex code ,the error is from Servicer_Id__c field. and it is showing" Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Servicer_Id__c')" in debug console.please help .Thanks

Comment: No, it's not from that field. It's from stuff before that field. You try to access "someObject.someField" but at runtime turns out "someObject" is null. Attempt to do "null.someField" = exception thrown. You pasted another code dump and only important area is retrieveCaseObject, right? So... Does that case really have Independent_Servicer__c lookup populated?

Comment: from this method we are trying to fetch the caseID but we are getting error VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT |caseId|null
 public static Case retrieveCaseObject(Id caseId){
        return [SELECT Id, Shipping_Address_1__c, Shipping_Address_2__c,Shipping_City__c, Shipping_State__c, Shipping_Postal_Code__c, Call_Back_Contact__c, Requested_Call_Back_Number__c,
                Requested_Call_Back_Number_Ext__c ,Independent_Servicer__r.Id, Independent_Servicer__r.Servicer_Id__c, Independent_Servicer__r.Name
            FROM Case
            WHERE Id = :caseId
            LIMIT 1
        ];
    }

Comment: it is  also showing "list has no rows for assignment to sobject'

Comment: Sounds like you're not passing `caseId` properly, maybe it's null and that messes your query up. Or it's valid but sharing rules mean this user's not allowed to see it? Note that in all your pasted Aura code there's zero "retrieveCaseObject", we can't tell how you're calling it. But sounds like you need some null checks, both in apex and in aura what to do if returned result is null, what if case is returned but Independent_Servicer__r is null...

Comment: yes, case id is not getting passed in above apex method , more over it is giving "list has no rows for assignment to sobject"

Comment: That's less important, you're getting it because "properly" you should be assigning query result to `List<Case>`, not just a single record. Precisely for situations where query returns 0 results (list can be then checked with isEmpty() etc). Post the aura code that calls that method, how do you obtain the case Id. Does your component have implements="force:hasRecordId"`, are you in normal salesforce or in Community page... eh

Comment: i have updated the code for case record fetch and it does implement hasrecordID.i am in normal salesforce.

Comment: `var newCaseId = caseRecord.recordId;` - has this ever worked? I'd expect `caseRecord.Id`. Put a breakpoint or `debugger;` statement before that line, enable setup -> debug mode on your user and experiment. And try `component.get('v.recordId');` too.

Comment: thanks.case id is not getting passed in it. i needed to build relation between claim and case then pass the id.it worked.Thanks for your response on every query , you helped me a lot in understanding the issue.